# Domain redirection from .co.uk to .com, same path after the /

Tags: dns, redirect

I'm trying to redirect www.domain.co.uk/ANYTHING_HERE to www.domain.com/ANYTHING_HERE, meaning anything and everything after the .co.uk will be forwarded to .com (this is where the site is actually hosted)

I have tried 301's and normal re directions and all sorts from cPanel but no luck, I have the domain as an addon at the moment, but can park the domain if required or simple redirect using .htaccess, any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think this question might be more suited for webmasters or serverfault.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess it would look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?)domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```